# file upload | without page refresh | struts2 | no flash |

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, struts2

Problem decription: I want to create a file upload screen using JSP. The screen will allow the user to select multiple files on the screen but there will be only one Upload button for all of them. On click of the upload button all the file objects should be obtained in the Action class.

But the important thing is the page should not get refreshed after submitting. There will be other information displayed on the same screen which should not get changed during the file upload is in progress.

My Attempts: I used the simple struts2 file upload feature which works fine. But it is refreshing the page on submitting. 
I used AJAX (JQuery) to resolve this. The problem I am facing with AJAX is that it is not setting the File object into the file property of Action class. Hence I am not able to obtain the file object in the Action class and process further.

Can anyone please help me with this.

I am attaching the code of whatever I have tried so far.

**JSP**:

```
<s:form action="fileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<s:file id="file" name="userImage" cssClass="fileUpload" cssStyle="fileUpload" />
<button id="px-submit">Upload</button>      
</s:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
$('.fileUpload').fileUploader();
});
</script>
```

**JQuery Plugin**:
[This is the jquery plugin that I have used.](http://pixelcone.com/fileuploader/)

**Action Class**:

```
public class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport{

private File userImage;

public File getUserImage() {
    return userImage;
}

public void setUserImage(File userImage) {
    this.userImage = userImage;
}

public String execute()
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("file name: " + userImage.toString());

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT: Here is my struts config file.

**Struts.xml**

```
<action name="commonDataImportAction_*" class="xxx.Action">
<result name="SUCCESS" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
             <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        </result>
```

I get a nullpointer here as the file object is not getting set.

Please help.

thanks in advance.
Gaurav

Comment: Try using HTML5 FileAPI for remote upload. You need to provide the upload URL that will receive the FILE that you're sending.

Comment: I am facing the same problem that you were asking for! Have you tried to upload file with posting other fields like`<s:textfield name="txtFileName"/>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the same plugin and it is working fine for me. The first problem I see in your code is that you have not set the type of your upload button to submit.

```
<button id="px-submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
```

Hopefully, this should solve the null pointer excepton.
Also, as mentioned in this plugin's docs, you need to return a json string

```
<div id='message'>success message</div>
```

on successfull upload. So you need to change your struts.xml mapping.
Try this and then get back to me if you face any further problems.
EDIT:
Ok here is my code as you requested

**JSP**

```
<form action="uploadImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="image" class="fileUpload" multiple/>
   <button id="px-submit" type="submit">Save all images</button>
   <button id="px-clear" type="reset">Clear all</button>
</form>

$('.fileUpload').fileUploader({
          autoUpload: false,
          buttonUpload: '#px-submit',
          buttonClear: '#px-clear',
});
```

**Action class**

You need to return stream result. I am using a plugin ([struts2 jquery plugin](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)) which takes care of it vary nicely, but you **dont** have to use it only because of this one requirement, instead I am giving you a code to return stream result without using any plugin.(Taken from [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/ajax.html))

```
public class UploadImageAction extends ActionSupport{
        private File image;
        private String imageContentType;
        private String imageFileName;
        //getter/setter for these
        public String execute() {
         String status="";         
        try{
              //save file code here    
         status="<div id='message'>successfully uploaded</div>"; //on success
         inputStream = new StringBufferInputStream(status);
        }catch(WhateverException e){
         status="<div id='status'>fail</div><div id='message'>Your fail message</div>"; //on error
         inputStream = new StringBufferInputStream(status);
         //other code
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }
    private InputStream inputStream;

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
       return inputStream;
    }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="fileUpload" class="com.xxx.action.UploadImageAction">  
    <result type="stream">
      <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
      <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    </result>
  </action>
```

Comment: Thanks Anu. Lets split this problem into two as you did. Firstly, I tried the type="submit" but no success. The file object in the Action class is still NULL! Can you please help me out with this thing first?

Regarding the second point, I will again check the docs and make the required changes. But as long as this is not impacting the first point, I can afford to put this on the back-burner. 

Also, if I may dare to ask, can you please share your code wherein you have done this successfully. May be that will help me more and I will not have to disturb here much.

Comment: As mentioned in the plugin docs, first try to submit without this plugin, the usual struts2 way(I mean with page refresh).If it works that way then only move to this plugin.Is it working that way? I will surely share my code no probs

Comment: Without the plugin is working. Am able to get the file object in the action class in usual struts2 way. Its only after using the plugin am facing this issue. Also i tried using the plugin with struts1. That works fine but am setting the form property in that case. I want it to work in struts2.

If you can help me by sharing your code, that would be great. /

Comment: Thanks!! that indeed worked!! Able to get file object in Action. Although only change that i can see the updating the <script> tag in JSP. Now comes the second part, how do I display the success message on the same JSP. Correct me if wrong, I need to use a <div> in the same JSP and set the message for this div in the Action class?If yes, then can you help me with that? Also pls check if my struts entry is correct or not `<action name="fileUpload" class="com.action.FileUploadAction">
   <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
   <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
  </action>`?

Comment: You need to return stream result type because ajax is being used here.Check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion. But the problem is after returning the status message is displayed on a new HTML page, rather than displaying on the same JSP. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Well this change is working in Firefox 15.0. But when I try it in IE7 the message is displayed in a separate HTML page. Browser issues?

Comment: Well i tried it on IE8 and its working, Can u show me your struts mapping

Comment: well guess what... the code started working in IE.. the error was an extra comma after `buttonClear: '#px-clear',` I didnt realize it at first but after looking closely at the code found this. Thanks for your help Anu. Appreciate it!

Comment: thats great.I am trying to modify this plugin to show thumbnail preview of the selected images before uploading.Lets see how much time it takes

Answer (score 0):

add a `target` attribute to your form and have an iframe with the same name. Submit the multipart form directly to the action without using any plugin and the response will load in the iframe. That will solve your page refresh issue. If you need to use a plugin then i'll suggest use http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ this will use XHR/Ajax for modern browsers and degrade gracefully to iframe upload in older browsers.

Comment: Thanks ankur. Regarding the first work-around. What should I suggest in the struts.xml file for result view in case of success? For eg. my current struts.xml entry is this:
    <action name="fileUpload" class="com.action.FileUploadAction">
    <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
What should be the target for success here?

Comment: I am not pretty much of a back end guy. You can try with any of the JSP page, it might load in the iframe. Or I don't know, may be you can skip defining results. As the form post automatically goes to the target iframe.

Comment: Can someone solve the problem of passing the File object from JSP to Java class with the above code setup? I guess if that is solved I can proceed further. Right now that is troubling me more.