# File Upload using AJAX in Struts2 without page refresh

Tags: file-upload, struts2

I want to upload file using Struts2, but without refreshing page.

How can I use AJAX for this solution.

```
$.ajax({
url:"strutsaction",
type : 'POST',
async: false,

});
```

What should I write for data and contentType in ajax request ?

jsp code:

```
<s:form action="strutsaction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <s:file name="imgFileUpload" label="Choose file to upload" accept="image/*"></s:file>
        <s:submit value="Upload" align="center"></s:submit>
    </s:form>
```

Comment: Which browsers do you want/need to support?

Comment: Chrome, Safari, IE and Firefox

Comment: Using `async: false` will make the browser unresponsive during the transaction, not recommended. Why don't you Google 'ajax file upload'? For a fully cross-browser solution, it's the best to use an existing wrapper or JS lib otherwise it's not that simple to write it from scratch.

Comment: You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` to upload files asynchronously, but it will not work in IE8 and below. Take a look at [this post](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/). For IE8 and below you can use hidden iframe upload. I am using [this plugin](http://pixelcone.com/fileuploader/) in my project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file upload | without page refresh | struts2 | no flash |](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878312/file-upload-without-page-refresh-struts2-no-flash)

Answer (score 0):

Hi the below code is working for me. I hope it will help you.

## JSP Code:

```
<div id="uploadImg">
     <s:form id="uploadImgForm" action="strutsaction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <s:file name="imgFileUpload" label="Choose file to upload" accept="image/*"></s:file>
            <s:submit value="Upload" align="center" id="uploadImgSubmitBtn"></s:submit>
     </s:form>
<div>
```

## JQuery:

```
$("#uploadImgSubmitBtn").click(function(e){

    // Get form
    var form = $('#uploadImgForm')[0];

    // Create an FormData object
    var data = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "strutsaction.action",
        data : data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('#uploadImg').html(data);
        }
    }); 
});
```